# Dotted/Dashed text

Tags: nodes, tikz-styles, alphabet

is there a way to write dashed or dotted letters such that they appear like normal but dotted or dashed?

i mean no word art or such things which i get when i use

```
 \pdfliteral{q 1 Tr [0.1 .8]0 d}#1\pdfliteral{Q}
```

my aim is text like the one in the following picture

[image: dotted text]

Comment: As far as I can tell: no. The fonts are saved with their outlines and not as a single stroke. You may could draw the outline dotted but that is not what you want. If you want dotted letters you have to finde a font that is drawn in that way … or create the strokes yourself using TikZ and Bezier curves etc.

Comment: You can only dash the outlines.  This is my best approximation: `\pdfliteral{q 1 Tr .5 w [0.5 0.5] 0d}`

Comment: @HenriMenke Dashed outlines... Oh that is cool!

Comment: Even it is eventually possible, it is easier to [download a new font](http://www.1001freefonts.com/dotted-fonts.php)

Comment: This dotted Arabic font may be a nice solution: https://www.arabictypography.com/retail-fonts/dotted-arabic-font